# Joomla Tags in 2 Columns - RocketTheme Template

Tags: templates, css, tags, layout, gantry

I'd love to know how I can create Joomla tags in two columns.

Example of what I have:
http://visualedgehosting.com/dfw-chimera/leadership/

Appreciate any help in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a **RocketTheme template**, and I see there is already a **custom.css** file.

```
templates/rt_chimera/css/rt_chimera-custom.css
```

The following css is an example you can use as starting base, to give the layout you want on that page. Place this code, at the end of your **rt_chimera-custom.css** file.

```
.tag-category .list-striped li {
    width: 45%;
    float: left;
}
.tag-category .list-striped li.cat-list-row0 {
    margin-right: 3%;
}

.tag-category .list-striped li img {
    width: 100% !important;
    max-width: 100% !important;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 8px 15px 8px 0px;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: @timmiller: You are welcome. Glad if that helped.

Answer (score 1):

There may be some clearer option in your template, but you could add the following lines to your CSS:

```
   .tag-category .list-striped li img {
        max-width: 25% !important;
        width: 100% !important;
   }

   .list-striped li, .list-striped dd, .row-striped .row, .row-striped .row-fluid {
        display: inline-block !important;
        width: 47% !important;
    }
```

Make sure this CSS is loaded after your template providers CSS

Answer (score 0):

Since the striped grey background looked strange in a two column format, I added this to remove it retaining the hover:

```
.list-striped li:nth-child(odd), .list-striped dd:nth-child(odd), .row-striped .row:nth-child(odd), .row-striped .row-fluid:nth-child(odd), .cat-list-row0 {
    background-color: rgba(232, 102, 102, 0);
}

.list-striped li:hover, .list-striped dd:hover, .row-striped .row:hover, .row-striped .row-fluid:hover, .cat-list-row0:hover, .cat-list-row1:hover {
    background-color: #ddd!important;
}
```

Thanks again!

Comment: Ok - well done. However keep in mind that this can not be considered as an answer to your question, as it is not answering the question of how to create 2 columns layout. Any other stylish details are irrelevant to the initial question. This answer would fit to a question on how to remove the undesired hover effect from 2 columns layout. As for the answers above, consider to vote up any of those that helped you, or even select one that solved your question.

Comment: Ah. Roger that. Will do so in the future. Thanks again.